# How to register FOSUserBundle in KnpRadBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I installed KNP Labs' KnpRadBundle and now I'm struggling to register FOSUserBundle. Anyone has ever registered a bundle in KnpRadBundle??

http://rad.knplabs.com/

Comment: Can you explain what have you tried so far?

Comment: added  "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "1.2.0" in the composer.json file and updated. It installed the bundle in vendors/, however when I try to activate it in kernel.yml, I get an error that the class can't be found. Seems like the bundle is never loaded, I tried to force it to load in my app_dev.php, but it didn't work either as then it won't find the classes used in the FOSUserBundle...

Comment: I feel dumb, I just got it to work! I wasn't activating it correctly... I had "- FOS\UserBundle" in the kernel.yml instead of "- FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle". How can I close this Question?

Answer (score 0):

My fault... Bundle name was missing in the kernel.yml

I had this:

```
- FOS\UserBundle
```

while it should be

```
- FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle
```

This is working now, sorry for having open a question that I answered myself :(

Comment: @Madenoiselle: what is the of kernel.yml. I can't see such Yml file under "app/". I just have AppKernel.php